# Handling error sent back by express in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with postman where i am sending my post data to api to insert data in mongodb.My issue is that i am not able to handle the error message properly. Here is my code for it

```
exports.addUser = (req, res, next) => {
  const db = getdb();
  // console.log(db)
  // console.log(db)
  db.collection12("user").insertOne({
    name: req.body.name,
    password:req.body.password
  }).then((result) => {
    res.send(result)  
  }).catch((err) => {
      res.status(404).send('Error in adding')
  });
};
```

so i knowingly made and error and wrote "collection12" so that i get and error but then in my catch method i am returning

> ("Error in addding")

so why then in postman i am not able to see this instead of that i am seeing a hude error meassge that says

[See error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgHb8.png)

I guess than same would be the issue in my react side where instead of getting my own error meassge i would get this huge message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't enter the `catch` block because it cannot even execute the db call. If you want a 404 error to be dispatched in this situation you need to add a try/catch statement like this:

```js
exports.addUser = (req, res, next) => {
  const db = getdb();
  // console.log(db)
  // console.log(db)

  try {
    db.collection12("user").insertOne({
      name: req.body.name,
      password:req.body.password
    }).then((result) => {
      res.send(result)  
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(404).send('Error in adding')
    });
  } catch {
    res.status(404).send('Error in adding')
  }
};
```